# Unsubscribe from a observable when condition is true in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, unsubscribe

I'm trying close a popup after 5 seconds when it is loaded but the subscription finish before so i want to unsubscribe when the variable loaded is true

```
    this.closed = false;
    this.loaded$.subscribe(loaded => {
      if (loaded) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.modalService.dismissActiveModal();
        }, 5000);
      }
    }).unsubscribe();
  }
```

Comment: Could you have a similar result using takeWhile or takeUntil from RxJS ? https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takewhile OR https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takeuntil

Answer (score 0):

```
this.closed = false;
// define the subscription
const subscription: Subscription = this.loaded$.subscribe(loaded => {
  if (loaded) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.modalService.dismissActiveModal();
      subscription.unsubscribe(); // unsubscribe here
    }, 5000);
  }
});
```

How about this?

Answer (score -1):

```
this.closed = false;
this.loaded$
.pipe(
  filter(loaded => loaded),
  switchMap(_ => interval(5000)),
  take(1),
  tap(_ => this.modalService.dismissActiveModal())
)
.subscribe();
```

Comment: This is not the answer to the question!

Comment: It unsubscribes when loaded is true by using take(1), it also dismissed the modal on a delay.

Comment: Please [edit] in explanations rather than commenting to update.

Comment: The code is self explanatory for anyone who knows Rxjs.